# display comment in post comment section without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, comments

im trying to make a facebook style post and comment section but i dont know how to display the data inserted to my database without refreshing the page...

this code is for saving the data to my db. i use `window.location.reload();` to reload my page so that the data will be displayed on my page..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name="mycomment"]').on('keyup', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var comments = $(this).val();
var sid = $(this).closest("div#userspost").find("input[type='hidden']").val();
if(e.keyCode == 13){        
if(comments.length)
$.ajax({
url: "../controller/post_controller.php",
type: "POST",
data:{ 
"id":sid,
"comments":comments,
},
success: function(data)
{

window.location.reload();
}
});
else
alert("Please write something in comment.");
}
});
}); 
</script>
```

using this script i can display my comment on a post i need to refresh the page first for me to be able to show the comment.

```
<?php 

foreach ($post_model->getcomment() as $value) {
if($postid == $value['post_uid']){

?>
<div id="mycomments">
<div class="col-lg-12" style="background:#eff9c7;">
<img src="./<?php echo $value['image']?>" class="pull-left" style="border-radius:50%;margin-top:10px;" width="7%" height="7%" />
<p style="margin-top:18px;line-height:15px;"><strong class="font-1" style="margin-left:10px;"><?php echo $value['firstname'].' '.$value['lastname']?></strong> <?php echo $value['pc_comment']?><br>
<span class="" style="margin-left:10px;font-size:.9em;color:gray;"><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $value['pc_datesend']?>"></abbr></span> 
</p>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

what im trying to do is that this is where i want to display my comments from my db. i tried researching about append/load but i dont exactly know how this works. is there any idea that i can display my comment in this script?

```
<div id="mycomments">
<div class="col-lg-12" style="background:#eff9c7;">
<img src="./<?php echo $value['image']?>" class="pull-left" style="border-radius:50%;margin-top:10px;" width="7%" height="7%" />
<p style="margin-top:18px;line-height:15px;"><strong class="font-1" style="margin-left:10px;"><?php echo $value['firstname'].' '.$value['lastname']?></strong> <?php echo $value['pc_comment']?><br>
<span class="" style="margin-left:10px;font-size:.9em;color:gray;"><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $value['pc_datesend']?>"></abbr></span> 
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you deliberately "flatten" the code before posting? or do you write code like that?

Comment: i flatten the code..

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write some pseudo code for you here. If you don't know how to store and fetch comments I would recommend looking into MYSQL.  It's relatively simple (for simple things), so that shouldn't be too big of a problem.  YouTube tutorials will be your blessing there.

You should have at least three files to properly implement this:

**uploadComment.php**

```
<?php

//process the comment upload
echo $_POST['comment'];

?>
```

**getComment.php**

```
<?php

//however you serve commnets, MYSQL, maybe?
//make sure it's properly formatted with HTML

?>
```

**index.html**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="Comment here" />
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="comments">

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("#submit").click(function () {
    $.post("uploadComment.php", {
        comment : $("#comment").val()
    }, function (data) {
        //comment posted.
        refreshComments();
    });
});

function refreshComments() {
    $.get("getComments.php", function(data) {
        $("#comments").html(data);
    });
}

setInterval(refreshComments,5000);


</script>
```

Note: Although it may be annoying, if you want immediate satisfaction, append the new comment to the end and then invoke refreshComments. (But I wouldn't recommend doing this because it would force you to update multiple locations in your code whenever you change your comment HTML format).

Comment: i can actually store the data from my db as you can see i also posted my loop for me to be able to display the stored data but i need to refresh the page first so that the stored comment shows up. what i wanted to do is without reloading the page i can display the data...

Comment: That's what the $.get does.  It will fetch your backend webpage for displaying comments and then display them to the page.

Comment: i got an error .. unexpected token on

 function refreshComments(function () {
    $.get("getComments.php", function(data) {
        $("#comments").html(data);
    });
}); <----here.

Comment: i will mark it as a solution if my problem will be resolve but not yet im still working on it.. no need to worry if this helps me i will mark it..

Comment: Sounds good, I am availiable on discord if you need help https://discord.gg/SjXTu3q

Comment: so after using the function you suggested after entering the latest comment what happens is after the setInterval  it removes the latest comment..

Comment: There's something wrong with the getComment.php or postComment.php